# SVM parameter tunning gives bad performance (R)

Tags: r, svm, cross-validation

So I have the following code, where I perform a SVM with the default parameters, and later I perform a parameter tunning with a 10 folds CV

```
library(readr)
library("e1071")
wdbc <- read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data", 
                   col_names = FALSE, col_types = cols(X1 = col_skip(), 
                   X2 = col_factor(levels = c("M", "B"))))

smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(wdbc))

set.seed(2)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(wdbc)), size = smp_size)

train <- wdbc[train_ind, ]
test <- wdbc[-train_ind, ]

model <- svm(X2~., data=train, kernel="radial", probability = TRUE)
predicted <- predict(model, test[,-1], probability = TRUE)

CM <- table(test$X2, predicted)
print(CM)

svm_tune <- tune(svm, train[,-1], train.y=train$X2, 
            kernel="radial", ranges=list(cost=10^(-1:2), gamma=c(.5,1,2)))
summary(svm_tune)

model_after_tune <- svm(X2~., data=train, kernel="radial", probability = TRUE, gamma = 0.5, cost = 10)
predicted <- predict(model_after_tune, test[,-1], probability = TRUE)

#attr(predicted, "probabilities")
CM <- table(test$X2, predicted)
print(CM)
```

When I print he Confusion Matrix for the default svm prediction, I got 3 missclassified points. When I tune the parameters, I got 15.
I have tried with different seeds, to see if I can get some better results, but it seems like the default parameters work better always.
Any clues why is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: might be that your parameter grid ranges are not good, so optimal parameters are simply not there

Comment: ranges=list(cost=seq(0.001, 5, by=0.1), gamma=seq(0.001, 5, by=0.1)) improves it a little bit, so now I got 5 missclassified samples.

Comment: what are the default parameters in `svm`?

Comment: cost = 1 and gamma = 1/(data_dimension)

Comment: your `cost=10^(-1:2)` includes the default value but does your `gamma`? you should check. might be that default value is best in this situation but you simply do not test it in your tuning routine.